# Concrete5: get pages in the root of the website

Tags: concrete5

I want to display all website pages on a single page in a tree structure (sort of like the existing sitemap). I can get a page by its ID, I can get children of a page, but how do I find pages that are in the root and do not have a parent? In other words, how do I get the first level on the tree?

EDIT: I found out that home page has ID = 1, and dashboard ID = 2. I hope it is like this in every installation of Concrete5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the answer in the code. This is how you get home page:

```
$home = Page::getByID(HOME_CID, 'RECENT');
```

And this is how you get the children:

```
$children = $home->getCollectionChildren();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 <?php echo View::url('/'); ?>
 <?php echo View::url('/some-page'); ?>
```

Comment: I need to get the Page/Collection object first